When should I use IAsyncAuthorizationFilter or AuthorizationHandler for authorization in ASP.NET Core Web API?
My understanding is that when I want to implement policy based authorization, I should simply use the out-of-the-box AuthorizationRequirement / AuthorizationHandler in conjection with the AuthorizeAttribute to achieve the authorization.
But when I want to implement a customized authorization strategy other than policy based, I should implement IAsyncAuthorizationFilter and do the customized authorization logic there. In such case, I don't want the AuthorizationRequirement / AuthorizationHandler constructs.
Is my understanding correct / accurate?
Another related question is that, for some OpenID Connect authz/authn solutions, the requested access_token will not carry the authorization information by default (like the information of Resource / Scope / Permission, etc.), in order to get the authorization information while doing the authn, another API call to /openid-connect/token endpoint should be made, with the grant_type being set to urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket, for example, in Keycloak. So, if I am going to check whether the current authenticated user would have access to any resource, I would firstly have to call this token API in the AuthorizationFilter or AuthorizationHandler implementations to get the authorization information and then check whether the user would have the permission. However, I don't think this is a good/elegant implementation since Authorization Filters/Handlers will be called each time when the protected API is invoked, which will be a big performance issue if there are API calls in the authorization filters/handlers. Are there any better ideas to implement this?
Thanks so much!
